# List all extension-only files and folders

Tags: ls

I'd like to list all files and folders that only have an extension, like `.bashrc`, `.cache/`, and so forth. This seems like it should be straightforward. When I try `ls .*`, I don't get the expected result:

````
jacob@jacob-Precision-Tower-3620:/home/jacob$ ls .*
.bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .ICEauthority  .profile

.:
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos

..:
jacob  lost+found

.cache:
event-sound-cache.tdb.d35b7efbc4794c7998a81437c01c41ec.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  evolution  fontconfig  gnome-getting-started-docs  gnome-software  gstreamer-1.0  ibus  logrotate  media-art  thumbnails  totem  tracker  update-manager-core  upstart  yelp

.config:
dconf  evolution  gnome-session  goa-1.0  gtk-3.0  ibus  libaccounts-glib  nautilus  parcellite  pulse  totem  update-notifier  upstart  user-dirs.dirs  user-dirs.locale  yelp

.gconf:

.gnupg:
private-keys-v1.d  S.gpg-agent

.local:
share

.nano:

.nv:
GLCache```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ls -A`, to show also hidden files (but not `.` and `..`: to include thest you may use `ls -a`).

For your case: `*` is expanded by the shell, so `ls` will see some files and some directories. If a directory is put as argument, it will list the files on that directory. You may use `ls -d *` to force to list files in argument, and not to list files in the directories in the arguments. Note: `ls -d .*` is not much different from `echo .*` (but for some formatting).